# Check if number is within the range of numbers of dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to check if 2351 is within below df column and return that value, which it is at 0 index. Is there any built in function to do this? I can edit my df column however I want(ex: removing "-" if it helps)

```
2352.86-2357.55
2357.55-2361.45
2806.46-2812.17
2801.56-2805.86
2796-2801.56
3261.2-3267.59
3711.47-3714.32
3721.02-3725.84
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you Split your column with:

```
data["ColumnName"].str.split("-", n = 1, expand = True)
```

And after with the following double condition: (to adapt with the column names)

```
 x=2351
 df['column1'].astype('float64')
 df['column2' ].astype('float64')
 df[(x >= df['column1']) & (df['column2' ] <= x)]
```